# How to manage the vim Mappings

Tags: vim, mapping

How to manage Vim Mappings, since each plugins (Pathogen is a great tool used to manage to manage Vim plugins) come with its own mappings. Collisions occur regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each plugin should come with a description (ideally accessible via the built-in `:help`) that includes the commands and mappings it defines. You need to read that anyway, in order to find out about the new functionality. You should also remember if one of the plugin's mappings clashes with an existing mapping of yours. `:verbose map ...` is a simple and great way to investigate your existing mappings.

In case of clashes, plugins using `:map <unique>` will fail noticeably, but most plugins will just silently overwrite a taken mapping. To fix that, a plugin should define `<Plug>...` mappings (see `:help using-<Plug>`; if it doesn't, complain to the author), which allow you to redefine the mappings (according to your tastes or to avoid a clash) in your `~/.vimrc`. For example:

```
:nmap <C-o> <Plug>EnhancedJumpsOlder
```

The same can also be used to disable a mapping altogether:

```
:nmap <Plug>DisableEnhancedJumpsNewer <Plug>EnhancedJumpsNewer
```

Unless you have a lot of custom mappings (e.g. to emulate a different editor's feel in Vim, which you shouldn't do), or you're using lots of plugins, clashes should not be that frequent.